# Open a socket to a remote server from inside a Java class

Tags: java, sockets, jpos

I'm trying  to open a socket that can send parameters from an user interface and send them to a remote server. What Java code can I use to open such a port of communication. Thank you

Comment: Do you really net JEE for that? Did you try this? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html

Comment: Thanks Klemens Morbe. Let me try that. What I really need to achieve is to send the messages with an IsoChannel using jPos. If what you're saying works then the jPos implementation should also work. Let me get on it, thanks